# Facebook Login ask to install (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I  need help in the facebook login from `Facebook-SDK-3.1`  for iOS 6.I have used all the code of the `Facebook sdk`sample  code `sessionLoginSample`,I have used the `WebView` opening code in this and whenever i login from the new id ...it takes me to the below image link to `install` in my `project` .dont know what exactly it is...and if i do so and after that `logout` from the code ..and when I again press button to login , it automatically `log-in` without asking for the ``` id and pssword``login page ```. and again again it automatically logs-in , even after logout./.can anyone help me why after being logout it ask stores the previous access token and password.

and **code** is

```
- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {

AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

  [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {

         appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]];
    }


    [appDelegate.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                                FBSessionState state,

                                                NSError *error) {

                FBSession.activeSession = session;



                                [self updateView];
                                NSLog(@" state=%d",state);

                                [FBRequestConnection
                                 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                   id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                                                   NSError *error) {

                                     userInfo = @"";


                                     userInfo = user.username;

                                     NSLog(@"string %@", userInfo); 
                                         [self checkfacebook];





                                 }];


                            }];    } 


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

FB grants access to your app once the user logs in . If the user wants to modify the privileges he can do it by loggin into fb and changing permissions. You might want to look into oAuth for further details.

Comment: I forgot to add. If you dont want to use this and just want to login via fb each time, then this is a wrong approach. but i have not worked in that area.

Comment: thanks but what else i can do ...bcz once i click on the install button and next time when i log-in again,it logs in automatically..even I have done logout.

Comment: its not about login or logout for a user. it is all about permission a user gives to your app. ie; what your app can do for you without your presence. like posting on your behalf. accessing contacts etc.

Comment: it would be better if you tell what do you want ?

Comment: simply i just want to login and logout in my app...and it returns me the  just `username` ...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/#protip3   does the changes required in this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23503/discussion-between-prajwal-udupa-and-christien)

Comment: you want to verify the user id then? then you can try directly with web view without oAuth. just give the url after no of attempts if the home screen appears (change in url) then consider success for that user id.

Comment: username i just needed to just display in my app...you means to say `openWithBehavior` i should use the normal which takes me to the WebView not pop-up like option..ryt.. but isnt possible in this>?

Comment: no bro what you are doing here is oAuth it is way too different from what you are implementing. The one thing you can try is after that delete your applications permissions programatically. But about this i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

As u login through new emailid it has to install your app for them...so,its asking for different login..but again u login with the same it will not ask...the answer for ur 2nd question is....is u doing something to the server side...bcoz there might be a provision on the server which remember user for few hour or few days...so,check with server side..if not working with server...reply me back i will try to answer further...

Comment: thanks..but whats the server side ??  .. but one id which is `FacebookAppID` in info plist for that id it will open the `FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView` on next login...but for the others ids , on next login it does not open any `FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView` means (pop up) ..it automatically gives me the username(in code) even if i have logout

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/#protip3   does the changes required in this?

Comment: ya man i know its a odd one ...but does not work for me ...even I have tried on the device and simulator both.

Comment: done but not works ...even if i use the sample code of the `facebook iOS sdk `  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample just to make `openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView` does not work ...you can try the same...

Comment: ya man!! i did the same ..downloaded from the same developers.facebook.com ..just to display u the code ..i used the github

Comment: you mean ..   `FBSession.activeSession=NULL;`  ryt...if i do so does not work ...i am not getting even i have used `[appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        [appDelegate.session close];` .how it is been taking the previous info

Comment: hey give me ur mail id ...i just u the sample code .. so that you can check

Comment: ya buddy ..Thanks a lot !! you can reply me the answer on the same  mail id

Comment: @Christien       srry just now seen ur msg..no not get time..try to see it today...

Comment: ok wenever you get time take a look..please till now I havent got the correct answer